# Parse plain text for email address using Xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a plain text like

```
...
Registrant Email: trinhtuanhung@gmail.com
...
Admin E-mail:ng2tuan@gmail.com
```

i try to put this into htmlagilitypack to pick out all email addresses but no result return

```
 var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(html);
 var emails= doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(text(), '@')]");
```

Comment: You cannot use your library on a file without HTML markup. In fact, you cannot use any XML/XSLT/XPath tool on plain text. I would suggest to use regular expressions on C# level to extract the mail addresses from your file.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do that with Xpath wehn your text file just contains plain text.
Try this instead:

```
    private static List<String> ExtractMailsFromFile(string filename)
    {
        string data = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection emailMatches = emailRegex.Matches(data);
        return (from Match emailMatch in emailMatches select emailMatch.Value).ToList();
    }
```